# Android App Bundle build fails

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have problem with building our app with new Google's feature which name is [App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/).

When I run `./gradlew app:packageProductionReleaseBundle --stacktrace` command, I receive:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageProductionReleaseBundle'.
            java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException: Error validating module 'base'.
                              ...
                           LONG STACK TRACE...
                              ...
Caused by: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/drawable/adoceansdk_close_interstitial_button.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.
                at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.BundleFilesValidator.validateModuleFile(BundleFilesValidator.java:112)
                at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.ValidatorRunner.lambda$validateBundleModules$6(ValidatorRunner.java:73)
                at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:406)
                at com.android.tools.build.bundletool.validation.ValidatorRunner.validateBundleModules(ValidatorRunner.java:73)
```

The reason for this is the external library in .jar we use.

How can I fix it without removing this library?

Thank you for the answer in advance.

Comment: If this external library is meant to be used in an Android app, I believe it should be exported as an AAR, not a JAR.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Comment: Thank you Pierre, it helps! I've added to the project library in AAR instead of JAR and it works!

Comment: @Pierre could write your comment as an answer? I will accept it as solution.

Comment: Done. Glad it helped :)

Comment: @jczerski I'm also facing the same problem. Error is: Caused by: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/drawable-hdpi/sym_keyboard_feedback_delete.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.  This file is located at below location 
 "AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\data\res\xml" but its not from third party jar file. Can you please suggest.

Comment: @Pierre maybe can help you :)

Comment: @chain I had the same problem and realised that one of the libraries I am using has a dependency on the Google Android Library » 4.1.1.4, which contains resource file sym_keyboard_feedback_delete.png and others that occupy the res directory. Excluding this module from the library dependancy has solved this issue. exclude group: 'com.google.android'  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263832/app-bundle-build-fails-because-of-the-sym-keyboard-feedback-delete-png-file/53278859#53278859

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this external library is meant to be used in an Android app, I believe it should be exported as an AAR, not a JAR. See https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Comment: I replaced all the jar files with their compatible aar file. Still i’m getting the same error while generating Android Archive Bundle.

Caused by: `com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException:` File `‘root/res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png’` uses reserved file or directory name ‘res’.

Answer (score -2):

One of the solution can be you get pre- compiled library file of this google module. I think a little google. search will help you. I myself would have done that but i didn't get the name of the module you are asking.

So, try and search for lib.so file this way you will get the functionality provided by the module as well now there will be no need to compile it.

One more advantage is that compiling the module from scratch results in much much bigger apk size while using precompiled libraries result in much lesser apk size.