# Android Error: "File 'root/res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_medium.9.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'."

Tags: android, build, nine-patch

My Android project has error while producing signed APK as below.

```
File 'root/res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_medium.9.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.ere
```

It didn't appear when I make APK without sining.

I found `popup_bottom_medium` is in android sdk (android-28) but I dont know why the error is happening on this specific file.

[image]

Please kindly  help us

let me put `build.gradle` in our code. Actually in this project, we using two self-made library. so totally we have three `build.gradle`.

1. `build.gradle` for app itself

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(path: ':mylibrary')

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'
    implementation project(path: ':ERSDKLogin')
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    // Measures against compile errors that occur when adding「'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0' 」
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'

    //graphLibrary
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
}
```

2. `build.gradle` for library one

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // TODO Remove and fix lint issues
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    }

    dependencies {
        api project(':aws-android-sdk-core')
        api project(':aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider')
        api project(':facebook-common')
        api project(':facebook-core')
        api project(':facebook-login')
        api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
        api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
        api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.4.0'
        api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5'
        api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.22'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.22'
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${project.ext.supportLibraryVersion}"
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
    repositories {
        flatDir{
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
```

2. `build.gradle` for library two

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':ERSDKLogin')

    compileOnly fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:1.0.0'
    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:1.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
}
```

Comment: update the image name popup_bottom_medium.9.png to popup.jpg and check. (Note .jpg or .png bothe are fine but don't give numeric in the image name)  thank u

Comment: .9.png is not a image format, just remove `.9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my 9-patch files in the `drawable` folder, not the `drawable-mdpi` etc... folders. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I realized the file is in android sdk (like: Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/data/res/drawable-mdpi/popup_bottom_medium.9.png).
it is not in our project so i don't think i can move it..

Comment: I'd look at any dependencies you've added since the last time you were able to successfully build an APK. One of those libraries must contain this resource and you'll need to exclude it:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/53278859/7434090

Comment: hi, I added build.gradle.
Actually this is the firast time to make signed APK from this project.

Answer (score 0):

file name change. eg popup_bottom_medium_9.png