# uses reserved file or directory name 'res'

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to signing an app by using gitlab pipeline. After commit and publish to gitlab app is coming pipeline and after 5 min. I'm getting this error like below

```
    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/drawable-hdpi/sym_keyboard_feedback_delete.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.
```

I don't know how to solve this issue. I don't know what you need to solve this. If you need to see something please let me know.

Here is my gradle file ;

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.bugsnag.android.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.packageName"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = ['appPackageName'               : 'com.packagename',
                                onesignal_app_id               : 'onesignal app id',
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE']
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false // shrink
            useProguard false   // don't obfuscate when set to FALSE

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true  // shrink
            useProguard true    // obfuscate

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations {
        cleanedAnnotations
        compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.3.94'
    implementation 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.6.3'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:4.+'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:11.6.0'


    implementation 'com.kochava.base:tracker:3.6.0'


    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.41.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Looks like this question is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263832/app-bundle-build-fails-because-of-the-sym-keyboard-feedback-delete-png-file/53278859#53278859

Comment: Tried it didnt work for me

Comment: Can you say how you depend on that dependency that pulls this resource?

Comment: I dont know how and and why pulls this resource. Normally I have never coded this resource in activity or somewhere. When I tried to build from terminal by typing gradlew build, it is working. I mean it is building. But when I tried from gitlab this error coming.

Comment: And also this resource is not in my project as you can understand from error.

Comment: [sym_keyboard_feedback_delete.png](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/sym_keyboard_feedback_delete.png).

Comment: what does it mean ? @MartinZeitler

Comment: that it is not required to package this file, because it is already on the device.

Answer (score 3):

```
android{  
 configurations {
        compile.exclude group: 'com.google.android'
    }
}
```

Solved it by adding this.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: if you don't have something like this library it might not be worked. The main idea is that you have a library containing resource file sym_keyboard_feedback_delete.png and others occupying the res directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk):

```
// Facebook Android SDK (everything)
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.0.0'
```