# Failed to build an Android App Bundle because it uses reserved file or directory name 'res

Tags: android, bundle, android-app-bundle

I am trying to build an aab, but it gets an error:

`File 'root/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.`

What do I have to do?
Are there any pre-requisites for AAB to work?
Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57416117/5978440)

Comment: You seem to have a dependency that is a .jar when it should be an .aar.